# Sequential Scan and Index Scan for primary key return different rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem with the data in my table `users`. This table has a primary key defined as:

```
"primary_c26a3d1a9d1c7aa4bb0a8d6b752c01a7" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

When I use a `WITH` clause to force a sequential scan on the table, I find duplicate IDs:

```
=> WITH temp_table AS (select * from "users") SELECT id from temp_table group by id having count(id) > 1;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
id | 8225700
-[ RECORD 2 ]
id | 8225682
...
```

How does this happen? If I search for these duplicates by index, I don't have the same problem:

```
=> select count(*) from users where id = 8225700;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
count | 1
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.

VACUUM did not help me. I tried to delete duplicates by ctid:

```
// good and bad rows
> with usrs as (select ctid, * from users) select ctid, id from usrs where id = 8225700;
ctid     |   id    
-------------+---------
(195669,33) | 8225700
(195708,34) | 8225700

// good row
select id, ctid from users where id = 8225700;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----
id   | 8225700
ctid | (195708,34)

// deleting bad row
DELETE FROM users WHERE ctid = '(195669,33)';
ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint   "foreign_1589fcbc580d08caf03e0fbaaca7d6dd" on table "account"
```

In detail:  Key (id)=(8225700) is still referenced from the `account` table.

But the real row has references and I can't delete it.

How can I delete these broken rows?

Comment: You have your `autovacuum` enabled, do you?

Comment: No DB is too big for autovacuum. But I can try it tonight.

Comment: If the DB is big you *have* to have autovacuum otherwise you'll get problems with the transaction id wraparound. Turning off autovacuum is almost always a bad idea (unless you do have a sufficient manual vacuum strategy in place)

Comment: Exact version? `SELECT version()` please. Also please `\x` then `SELECT * FROM pg_database WHERE datname = current_database();`. Is there anything informative in the PostgreSQL server logs? At best this probably indicates index or heap corruption, but horse is right in that xid wraparound is also a very real concern. Please show the output of `WITH temp_table AS (select ctid, xmin, xmax, * from "users") SELECT ctid, xmin, xmax, id from temp_table group by id having count(id) > 1;` and `select ctid, xmin, xmax from users where id = 8225700;` . Edit the question, comment here when done.

Comment: Version: PostgreSQL 9.1.7 on x86_64-alt-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-alt-linux-gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20101130 (ALT Linux 4.5.1-alt8), 64-bit

options: datname => databasename, datdba => 16384, encoding => 6, datcollate => ru_RU.UTF-8, datctype => ru_RU.UTF-8, datistemplate => f, datallowconn => t, datconnlimit => -1, datlastsysoid => 12485, datfrozenxid => 65889251, dattablespace => 1663, datacl => {=Tc/da,da=CTc/da}.

We have problems with autovacuum - it too hard for our highload project and administrators turned off it.

Comment: This sql is boken: "WITH temp_table AS (select ctid, xmin, xmax, * from "users") SELECT ctid, xmin, xmax, id from temp_table group by id having count(id) > 1;" becouse after WITH it has not additional fields like "ctid".

Comment: This one of broken rows: "ctid => (195665,9), xmin => 246066687, xmax                            => 246066687, id => 8225682" wich could not see by index.

Comment: **Edit your question** to add info, so it's readable, please, and show it as a copy and paste of the query and results. Let me know when it's done and I'll take a look. As for autovacuum: if you turn it off, *you are creating a serious and growing problem* unless you manually vacuum instead. As for the broken query: Er, oops. Please just get the IDs for which there are duplicates, then `SELECT ctid, xmin, xmax FROM "users" WHERE id = ...` for those IDs.

Comment: Anyway, the good news is that this probably isn't an xid wraparound problem, though I can't be sure without seeing *all* the broken rows for a given ID. Your datfrozenxid is `65889251` which is << the xid range `246066687-246066687`  for the broken row, so you probably have no issues with xid wrap-around there. `SELECT txid_current()` would confirm.

Comment: I cant give broken rows by id, because it is not exist (searching by index);
`=> select id, ctid, xmin, xmax from users where id in (WITH t AS (select * from "users") SELECT id from t group by id having count(id) > 1);
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----
id   | 8225700
ctid | (195708,34)
xmin | 246066245
xmax | 254176460
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----
id   | 8225682
ctid | (195708,16)
xmin | 246066137
xmax | 246066139
`

Comment: `-[ RECORD 3 ]-----
id   | 8225732
ctid | (195677,47)
xmin | 246066377
xmax | 253507784
-[ RECORD 4 ]-----
id   | 8225719
ctid | (195677,44)
xmin | 246066329
xmax | 246460522
-[ RECORD 5 ]-----
id   | 8225710
ctid | (195708,44)
xmin | 246066286
xmax | 246066288
-[ RECORD 6 ]-----
id   | 8225672
ctid | (195708,65)
xmin | 261877460
xmax | 0
`

May be this query can helps?

Comment: Please, don't post queries and their results as comments. *Edit your question instead!*

Comment: Okey, I placed some queries to question. Sorry for unreadable comments.

Comment: What about trying to modify the broken record's userid so the FK constraint no longer applies? `update users set id = -1 where ctid = '(195669,33)';`

Comment: Since there is a foreign key problem, we might need to know what is the definition of the users table and account table and what is the relationship between them.

Comment: Hi! I can't show tables information, because we created new version of our product and migrated all data to new structure of postgres db. But I can say, we resolved this issue by help of disabling table-triggers and delete broken rows by ctid.

Comment: Have you tried EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see the plan of query executions? Maybe that will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> // deleting bad row DELETE FROM users WHERE ctid = '(195669,33)';
> ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key
> constraint   "foreign_1589fcbc580d08caf03e0fbaaca7d6dd" on table
> "account"
>
> In detail: Key (id)=(8225700) is still referenced from table
> "account".
> ```

It says quite clearly: The row is referenced by `account` table.

You need to locate the reference and fix it.

```
UPDATE account SET fkey_field = ??? WHERE ... ;
```

Details depend on structure and contents of `account` table.

If you want more help, please paste full output of `\d account` and `\d users` from psql.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad index to me. Try rebuilding your indexes.

```
reindex table users
```